# Building OpenCV with Java Support on Mac OS X (64-bit)

Tags: opencv

Following directions from http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.4-beta/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html, I am running into the this:

> make -j8
>   ...
>   ...
>   Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_java244.dylib
>   ld: unknown option: -whole-archive
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_java244.dylib] Error 1
>
>   make[1]: *** [modules/java/CMakeFiles/opencv_java.dir/all] Error 2
>   make: *** [all] Error 2

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had literally the exact same problem! With some digging, I found that the linker ld has different flags in Unix and OS X. Thus the error:

```
ld: unknown option: -whole-archive
```

To fix, you can edit the file `modules/java/CMakeLists.txt` to use the OS X flags. (search for `-whole-archive`)

Original:

```
target_link_libraries(${the_module} -Wl,-whole-archive ${__deps} -Wl,-no-whole-archive ${__extradeps} ${OPENCV_LINKER_LIBS})
```

New:

```
foreach(_dep ${__deps})
  target_link_libraries(${the_module} -Wl,-force_load "${_dep}")
endforeach()
```

I'm going to see if I can get these changes into the repo. :)

**--Edit--**
My original answer was slightly wrong (but partly right!); I've changed the answer above. -force_load only works for one archive, thus the foreach. As well, it should go to the linker, thus the -Wl. See [pull request 741](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/pull/741) for details and git pull for up-to-date code.

Answer (score 22):

One of the easiest solution to install OpenCV is to use [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

All what you need to do is just type:

```
brew tap homebrew/science
brew install opencv --with-java
```

It will automaticaly load needed libs and build opencv.

When it will be done, you will be able to find a jar file in

```
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.9/share/OpenCV/java/
```

[image: opencv path]

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you for this.  I installed OpenCV via homebrew as well.  I just wanted to know where the JAR file was.  +1.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing you're building from source. If so, I recommend using CMake.
I've managed to build OpenCV 2.4.4 with the Java module by enabling it using ccmake:

```
cd OpenCV-2.4.4
mkdir build
cd build
ccmake ..
```

Make sure `BUILD_opencv_java` is `ON` (should be on by default)
[image: OpenCV java]

After you're done with the settings:

1. press configure(`c`)
2. press generate(`g`)
3. continue with the usual `make`, `make install`

For convenience I've also uploaded the Java wrapper built for x86_64 on osx 10.8:

- [libopencv_java.dylib](http://lifesine.eu/so/libopencv_java.dylib)
- [opencv-2.4.4.jar](http://lifesine.eu/so/opencv-2.4.4.jar)
- [opencv-2.4.4.jar.dephelper](http://lifesine.eu/so/opencv-2.4.4.jar.dephelper)

Comment: Could you link the Java wrapper for opencv 2.4.11 (32 bit version) compiled with JDK 1.6? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34103709/build-opencv-jdk-6-32-bit-for-mac?noredirect=1#comment55959146_34103709)

Comment: How do you initialise the native library with 2.4.4 seeing that you cannot call System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME); ?

Answer (score 4):

My Solution for this was to use MacPort installation ... it put every thing you need and you have no worries about config , builds and so on...

Just Install MacPort and then run: "sudo port install opencv +java"

for more details see: http://ladstatt.blogspot.com.br/2013/04/opencv-on-macosx-with-java-support.html