# OpenCV: make -j8 won't create jar lib

Tags: opencv

I am trying to build OpenCV to have Java wrapper acc. to this [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.11/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html).

When I run

```
make -j8
```

**the bin/opencv-244.jar should be created, but it's not** and there is no error in console.

(I have OSX El Capitan)

Comment: See [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/12/19/install-opencv-3-on-macos-with-homebrew-the-easy-way/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25724226/5008845). Also install the latest version 3.2.0 instead of the obsolete 2.4.4